# eval alternative to processing rules in PHP?

Tags: php, eval

I know finding alternatives to `eval()` is a common topic, but I'm trying to do something I've not done before.  I am processing known-format CSV files, and I have built rules for how the data will be handled depending on the source columns available.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing.  In this example, `$linedata` represents a single row of data from the CSV file.  `$key["type"]` points to the column I need the data from.  If this column holds the value of "IN", I want `$newcol` set to "individual", else "organization".

```
$key["type"] = 12;
$linedata[12] = 'IN';
$rule = '($linedata[($key["type"])] == "IN" ? "individual" : "organization");';
eval ('$newcol = ' . $rule);
```

So `$rule` stores the logic.  I can run a filter on the `$linedata` array to try and protect from malicious code coming from the CSV files, but I wonder if there is a better way to store and process rules like this?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the rules are made. Are you trying to evaluate php code you got from a csv file, or are the rules defined in your processing code? If the rules are defined in your processing code, why don't you just use a function?

Comment: Actually, it would help to see a snippet of the data and the processed output. It seems like all you are trying to do is a mapping, and there's no need of `eval` for that.

Comment: @netcoder - yes, I am trying to do a mapping, but the problem is that the CSV files don't always have columns in the same order (which is why I have to define a key).  I'll edit the question to try and make it more clear, because the answers aren't on target yet.

Comment: @FrancisAvila - The rules change depending on the source of the CSV files, which come in several different formats.  The more I think about this (short on sleep, should have thought more before asking), the more I think you are right and I just need a series of conditionals to map out the data.  I'll see if I need to clarify the question further after getting some sleep. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store arbitrary PHP in a CSV file and then expect it to work without calling `eval` (or similar functionality).

The safe way to do what you're asking for is to treat the file as *data*, not code.

This is why languages like BBCode exist: you can't have an inert language trigger active features directly, so you create an easy-to-interpret mini-scripting-language that lets you achieve what you want.

In other words, you cannot store active "rules" in the file without interpreting them somehow, and you cannot simultaneously allow them to contain arbitrary PHP and be "safe". So you can either attempt to parse and restrict PHP (don't, it's tough!) or you can give them a nice easy little language, and interpret that. Or, better yet, don't store logic in data files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just to be clear the rules are stored in my code - not in the CSV.  The CSV file is just data that needs to be processed differently depending on how the data is structured.  I think I am over-complicating the problem, though, and will update my question tomorrow.

Comment: I think this is the best answer considering how poorly I asked the question. In my case, I completely changed the logic into series of switch statements to avoid eval altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I was **wrong**.

---

I can be wrong, however `create_function` may be good enough.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: `create_function` is scarcely better than `eval`.

Comment: @Borealid You are right. There are too many ways to create string `GLOBALS` and use `$$`...

Comment: @Borealid Why is it safer? From PHP Manual: `Caution
create_function() function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). `

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev The word "scarcely" means "not significantly" in this context.